# Email with extra '.com' behind sender email address

Tags: email, thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-client

Currently I had a situation where I sent an email to `xxx@abc.com.tw`, but when I receive mail from `xxx@abc.com.tw`, it showed as `xxx@abc.com.tw.com`, with extra '.com' behind the email address, this just happen within this week. Before this, I didn't change any setting, currently I am using Outlook 2010.

When I checked the email in webmail, it also showed it as `xxx@abc.com.tw.com`. It seem that it has nothing to do with Outlook. However, I also tried on Thunderbird 16.0.1, but still the problem is the same.

Has anyone experienced this before? Is the problem caused by the sender or receiver?

P/S: Sender email address display as `xxx@abc.com.tw` in Gmail account.

Header Message as below:

> Return-Path: Alice@pointsoft.com.tw.com
>   Received: from colo4.roaringpenguin.com (not-assigned.privatedns.com [174.142.115.36] (may be forged))
>   by pioneerpos.com (8.12.11/8.12.11) with ESMTP id q9V6OsKU032650
>   for Bob@pioneerpos.com; Wed, 31 Oct 2012 01:24:55 -0500
>   Received: from mail.pointsoft.com.tw (pointsoft.com.tw [59.124.242.126])
>   by colo4.roaringpenguin.com (8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.4) with ESMTP id q9V6OmN0026374
>   for Bob@pioneerpos.com; Wed, 31 Oct 2012 02:24:50 -0400
>   X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft Exchange V6.5
>   Content-class: urn:content-classes:message
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>   boundary="----_=_NextPart_001_01CDB730.6B3D5A51"
>   Subject: =?big5?B?scTByrPmLblzpfM=?=
>   Date: Wed, 31 Oct 2012 14:25:16 +0800
>   Message-ID: 
>   X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
>   X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
>   thread-topic: =?big5?B?scTByrPmLblzpfM=?=
>   thread-index: Ac23MH3YpZuLx2ejTYqR5PfoZ+IoBw==
>   X-Priority: 1
>   Priority: Urgent
>   Importance: high
>   From: "Alice" Alice@pointsoft.com.tw.com
>   To: "Bob"  Bob@pioneerpos.com
>   X-Spam-Score: undef - pointsoft.com.tw is whitelisted.
>   X-CanIt-Geo: ip=59.124.242.126; country=TW; region=03; city=Taipei; latitude=25.0392; longitude=121.5250; http://maps.google.com/maps?q=25.0392,121.5250&z=6
>   X-CanItPRO-Stream: pioneerpos-com:default (inherits from rp-customers:default,base:default)
>   X-Canit-Stats-ID: 02IhGoMJb - 2e7fa924443e - 20121031
>   X-CanIt-Archive-Cluster: irqpXI7aJGyo4Ewta7qVH399FOg
>   X-Scanned-By: CanIt (www . roaringpenguin . com) on 174.142.115.36

Comment: You are Alice@pointsoft.com.tw.com sending to Bob@pioneerpos.com ?

Comment: i am bob@pioneerpos.com sending to alice@pointsoft.com.tw
but when i receive reply email from alice, the email address showed as alice@pointsoft.com.tw.com

Comment: So please provide also the message header from your mail to Alice@pointsoft.com.tw .

Comment: I cannot find any header message in the mail that sent to alice@pointsoft.com.tw

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you're using a [`Reply-To:` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Message_header).
This may be the source of the different reply address.

If this is not the case please add the message header for further investigations.

Comment: Hi Schmitt, maybe my description is not clear enough. This happen when i receive reply email from xxx@abc.com.tw where i sent out at earlier time. Below is the hear msg. Thanks

Comment: Please provide the message header in your question and remove the unreadable comments here ;-)

Comment: sorry, newbie here.  
still learning, i already add the header in the question part

Answer (score 0):

This is just due to the person that owns the @abc.com.tw misconfiguring their email client.

As you will have noticed when you configured outlook and thunderbird, you can put anything you like in the "From" email address when defining an account.  This is not verified, it is up to you to get it right (assuming you can set up the other settings manually).

They have entered the wrong address when configuring their email (or their email server is misconfigured).

Just email them and let them alert their IT people, there is nothing you can do at your end, and nothing you can have done to cause this.

Comment: Hi,  probably you are right, the cause might due to the misconfiguring of sender email cleint or mail server faulty.
but when they send to my gmail account, the display seem normal, display as @abc.com.tw
so do you have any idea?

Comment: @CHT Not without more details about their environment - something within it is setting the from: address incorrectly, but I couldn't guess what that might be.

Comment: alright, at least i know it had something to do  with the "from" setting. thank you for point out. will keep you inform if there is any update..thanks